# Can I buy a .CA if I have no affiliation with Canada?

Tags: domains, top-level-domains

Well, the title says it all. It seems by CIRA (http://www.cira.ca/home-en/?lang=en) that I cannot, but the website doesn't make it explicitly clear how they check or anything like that...

I have a domain name that I'd love to register for a business that will likely start in the US (where I'm based), but hopefully will grow globally (probably including Canada), but I want to build a brand around the domain name, and I do not want to get slammed by Canada yanking the domain name back if they discover I have no connection there.

I only have experience with .com and .us domain names, so this is new territory for me. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

It does appear that you would need to be a citizen, but I am unsure if they would be able to enforce it to that extent.

"Subject to Canadian Presence Requirements."
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#sortable_table_id_1
According to this document from easyDNS, you are required to have citizenship.
http://support.easydns.com/canpresence.php3

Comment: Yeah, that's what I read on CIRA's website. But it seems that I could pretend to be a citizen and register anyway... but do I risk losing the domain name in the future if they do any investigation?